# Scala Multiple type parameter that are defined later

Tags: scala, generics, type-conversion, generic-programming

I am trying to port a generic library for Haskell to Scala. However, I am currently not really happy with how I solved the generic Crush function in Scala.

I defined to following treats to handle Crush functions.

```
trait FRep[G[_],F[_]]{
    def frep[A](g1 : G[A]) : G[F[A]]
  } 

trait Crush[B,A]{ 
    def selCrush : Assoc => A => B => B
}
```

Next, I wanted to define the crush function, but here I ran into problems. The problem is that I need this FRep trait to represent the Crush function, but the G(Generic) in frep only allows 1 parameter. I solved this using lambda types, but I still have some problems to define a function. This is the approach I wanted to work:

```
def crush[B,A,F[_]](asc : Assoc)(f : A => B => B)(z : B)(x : F[A])(implicit rep : FRep[({type AB[A] = Crush[B,A]})#AB,F]): B = {
    def fCrush = new Crush[B,A]{ 
      override def selCrush= _ => f
    }
    return(rep frep(fCrush).selCrush(asc)(x)(z))
}
```

This obviously gave an error, because the A parameter in the crush function is not the same as the A lambda type in the implicit rep variable, which needs to be same in order to use the Crush function. This is the error I received:

```
<pastie>:677: error: type mismatch;
 found   : x.type (with underlying type F[A])
 required: A
       return(rep frep(fCrush).selCrush(asc)(x)(z))
```

So, the solution I came up with is to split the crush function into more parts, such that I could use the same A for the crush function. This is the current solution that compiles:

```
class CrushFunction[B,F[_]](asc : Assoc)(z : B)(implicit rep : FRep[({type AB[A] = Crush[B,A]})#AB,F]){
    def crush[A](f : A => B => B)(x : F[A]) : B = {
        val crushVal = new Crush[B,A]{
            override def selCrush:  Assoc => A => B => B = _ => f
        }
        return(rep.frep(crushVal).selCrush(asc)(x)(z))
    }
}
```

So, my question is: Is there a nicer way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the only thing wrong with your first solution is that you left out the dot between `rep` and `frep`. I would also advise you not to use `return` explicitly, and not to shadow names of type parameters (`A`):

```
def crush[B,A,F[_]](asc : Assoc)(f : A => B => B)(z : B)(x : F[A])(implicit rep : FRep[({type AB[X] = Crush[B,X]})#AB,F]): B = {
    def fCrush = new Crush[B,A]{ 
      override def selCrush: Assoc => A => B => B = _ => f
    }
    rep.frep(fCrush).selCrush(asc)(x)(z)
}
```

Now you may ask yourself: why this error message if all that's wrong is a missing dot? Well, scala supports infix notation. It parses `a b c d e` as `a.b(c).d(e)`. But you wrote something like this: `a b(c).d(e)`. This confuses the parser. You can see what happens when you append `//print` to your code in the REPL (version 2.11.8 or higher I think) and press the TAB key.

I filtered out all the cruft for you. `rep frep(fCrush).selCrush(asc)(x)(z)` gets parsed as:

```
rep.frep[A](fCrush.selCrush(asc)(x)(z))
```

In that expression `x` is indeed required to be of type `A` instead of `F[A]`.

<s>Honestly: to me it seems a bit like a bug that scalac managed to parse your dotless code, completely ignoring a parenthesis in the process.</s>
Let's call it an unfortunate syntax quirk :-)

Comment: -Xlint for shadowed type param. How would you parse `"hello" +("world").length` ?  I think they want to add an annotation to indicate what members (operators) can be used infixedly. That's to help readability, but maybe an Abide rule could warn about alnum infix not followed by whitespace (etc).

Comment: You are right. That works! Thank you for the great explanation!